# Fish & ansi-term text background colour

Tags: spacemacs, ansi-term

I'm using fish as my default shell and spacemacs config layers in emacs. My default term is an ansi-term.

Does ansi-term support text background colours? Foreground (text) colours seem to work fine!

[image]

Thanks!